# Map cycle values (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, dictionary, recursion, functional-programming

thanks for reading!

So I'm making a program that gives you solutions for possible alphametics equations (if you don't know what that is keep on reading please, it doesn't matter so much). It lets you input three words, two to add up and one as the answer, and the range of possible digits you want assigned to each character. Then it should try and give you all possible assignments of characters to letters that work.

Ok, if none of the above made sense  its not important.
So I've got this map.

```
NavigableMap<Character, Integer> myMap = new TreeMap<Character, Integer>();
```

And this map gets assigned a bunch of unique characters as keys and a range of numbers as values. For example, lets say I have a range 1-5 of values. And I've got the chars J O S as keys in the map. I want the map to start looking something like this:

> [J=1, O=2, S=3]

Then I will use those mapped values to test for something (if my alphametics equation works), and then I will continue with the next key value assignments

> [J=1, O=2, S=4]

Again, I want the program to test, then cycle again

> [J=1, O=2, S=5]

And again

> [J=1, O=3, S=2]
>
> [J=1, O=3, S=4]
>
> [J=1, O=3, S=5]
>
> [J=1, O=4, S=2]
>
> [J=1, O=4, S=3]
>
> [J=1, O=4, S=5]
>
> [J=1, O=5, S=2]
>
> [J=1, O=5, S=3]
>
> [J=1, O=5, S=4]
>
> [J=2, O=1, S=3]
>
> [J=2, O=1, S=4]
>
> [J=2, O=1, S=5]
>
> [J=2, O=3, S=1]
>
> [J=2, O=3, S=4]
>
> [J=2, O=3, S=5]

etc etc, until I've had every possible combination of unique mappings and I end up with:

> [J=5, O=4, S=3]

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best way to approach this?

Comment: Hint: if there are `m` characters and `n` integers to choose from, can you reduce it to the case with `m-1` characters and `n-1` integers?  And how might you deal with 1  character and `n-m-1` integers?